# Rewrite a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

Fix $r$ and $d\equiv r+\binom{r}{2}$ and consider $d$ real numbers $b_1,b_2,..., b_d$.

I have the following system of linear equations: 
$$
\begin{cases}
\text{$(\diamond)$ Differences between the elements $\{b_1,b_h\}$ for $h=2,...,r$   $\hspace{1cm}$ ($r-1$ elements)}\\
b_{r+1}=b_1-b_2\\
b_{r+2}=b_1-b_3\\
...\\
b_{2r-1}=b_1-b_r\\
-------\\
\text{$(\diamond)$ Differences between the elements $\{b_2,b_h\}$ for $h=3,...,r$ $\hspace{1cm}$ ($r-2$ elements)}\\
b_{2r}=b_2-b_3\\
...\\
b_{3r-3}=b_2-b_r\\
-------\\
\text{$(\diamond)$ Etc. }\\
....\\
-------\\
\text{$(\diamond)$ Differences between the elements $\{b_{r-1},b_h\}$ for $h=r$ $\hspace{1cm}$ ($1$ element)} \\
b_d=b_{r-1}-b_r
\end{cases}
$$

**Question:** For any $r$, I want to re-write in an **EQUIVALENT** way such that it

- has only relations with the $+$ sign on the RHS of each equation
- has only 1 variable on the LHS
- has all the variables on the LHS different between each other
- has the least possible amount of equations

I'm unable to find a generic expression. Below I report my attempts which should also clarify what I'm trying to do.

---

**My attempts:** 
For $r=2$, the original system is
$$
\begin{cases}
b_3=b_1-b_2
\end{cases}
$$
which simply can be written as 
$$
\begin{cases}
b_1=b_2+b_3
\end{cases}
$$
which satisfies my requirements.

---

For $r=3$, the original system is
$$
\begin{cases}
b_4=b_1-b_2\\
b_5=b_1-b_3\\
b_6=b_2-b_3\\
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
b_1=b_2+b_4\\
b_1=b_3+b_5\\
b_2=b_3+b_6
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
b_1=b_3+b_6+b_4\\
b_1=b_3+b_5\\
b_2=b_3+b_6
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
b_1=b_2+b_4\\
b_2=b_3+b_6\\
b_5=b_6+b_4\\
\end{cases}
$$
which satisfies my requirements.

---

For $r=4$, the original system is 
$$
\begin{cases}
b_5=b_1-b_2\\
b_6=b_1-b_3\\
b_7=b_1-b_4\\
b_8=b_2-b_3\\
b_9=b_2-b_4\\
b_{10}=b_3-b_4
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
b_1=b_2+b_5\\
b_1=b_3+b_6\\
b_1=b_4+b_7\\
b_2=b_3+b_8\\
b_2=b_4+b_9\\
b_3=b_4+b_{10}
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
b_1=b_2+b_5\\
b_1=b_4+b_{10}+b_6\\
b_1=b_4+b_7\\
b_2=b_4+b_{10}+b_8\\
b_2=b_4+b_9\\
b_3=b_4+b_{10}
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
b_1=b_2+b_5\\
b_2=b_3+b_8\\
b_3=b_4+b_{10}\\
b_7=b_{10}+b_6\\
b_9=b_{10}+b_8\\
\end{cases}
$$
which satisfies my requirements. In principle, as I keep increasing $r$, I should be able to find some path, but I don't see anything!